# Java: Saving User Input to be Calculated in a Loop

Tags: java, loops, user-input

Unfortunately, I can't attach my overall program (as it is not finished yet and still remains to be edited), so I will try my best to articulate my question.

Basically, I'm trying to take an integer inputted by the user to be saved and then added to the next integer inputted by the user (in a loop).

So far, I've tried just writing formulas to see how that would work, but that was a dead end. I need something that can "save" the integer entered by the user when it loops around again and that can be used in calculations.

Here is a breakdown of what I'm trying to make happen:

1. User inputs an integer (e.g. 3)
2. The integer is saved (I don't know how to do so and with what) (e.g. 3 is saved)
3. Loop (probably while) loops around again
4. User inputs an integer (e.g. 5)
5. The previously saved integer (3) is added to this newly inputted integer (5), giving a total of (3 + 5 =) 8.
6. And more inputting, saving, and adding...

As you can probably tell, I'm a beginner at Java. However, I do understand how to use scanner well enough and create various types of loops (such as while). I've heard that I can try using "var" to solve my problem, but I'm not sure how to apply "var". I know about numVar, but I think that's another thing entirely. Not to mention, I'd also like to see if there are any simpler solutions to my problem?

Comment: Use two variables, defined outside the loop: `int currentInput = 0; int sum = 0`. Then, within the loop, read the user input into `currentInput` and add it to `sum`.  Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Do you want to decrement your sum everytime you loop? Or give -ve numbers to cancel it out?

Comment: @UmaKanth: I want to continuously add the newly inputted integer to the sum of all previously inputted integers. Your answer was very helpful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay So what you want is to store a number.

So consider storing it in a variable, say `loopFor`.

```
loopFor = 3
```

Now we again ask the user for the input.

and we add it to the `loopFor` variable.

So, we take the input using a `scanner` maybe, Anything can be used, Scanner is a better option for reading numbers.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);//we create a Scanner object
int numToAdd = scanner.nextInt();//We use it's method to read the number.
```

So Wrapping it up.

```
int loopFor = 0;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);//we create a Scanner object

do {
    System.out.println("Enter a Number:");
    int numToAdd = scanner.nextInt();//We use it's method to read the number.
    loopFor += numToAdd;
} while (loopFor != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just have a `sum` variable and add to it on each iteration:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create scanner for input
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    int sum = 0;
    System.out.println("Please enter a number (< 0 to quit): ");
    int curInput = userInput.nextInt();
    while (curInput >= 0) {
        sum += curInput;
        System.out.println("Your total so far is " + sum);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number (< 0 to quit): ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer but, let's not forget the person who asked is a beginner. You're using intermediate constructs, IMHO.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm not sure how to deal with "(< 0 to quit)" as of now, but I'll keep this in mind for future use.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // This will keep track of the sum
    int sum = 0;
    // This will keep track of when the loop will exit
    boolean errorHappened = false;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            // Created to be able to readLine() from the console.
            // import java.io.* required.
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            // The new value is read. If it reads an invalid input
            // it will throw an Exception
            int value = Integer.parseInt(bufferReader.readLine());
            // This is equivalent to sum = sum + value
            sum += value;
        } 
        // I highly discourage the use Exception but, for this case should suffice.
        // As far as I can tell, only IOE and NFE should be caught here. 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errorHappened = true;
        }
    } while(!errorHappened);
```

Comment: What if I wanted to add 11 or some number which isn't a single digit?

Comment: @UmaKanth The System.in.read() will read anything you write till you press enter.

Comment: You might wanna look at it again, It would only consider the first character.

Comment: Instead of just "writing the code", you should explain your solution. OP does not learn anything, if you do not explain. And by the way: it would be a nice gesture to at least mention my comment.

Comment: @UmaKanth my bad. Made some edits. I wasn't really checking it on an actual Java editor.

Comment: @Turing85 How about instead of being so self-righteous, you provide an answer. There's going to be at least ten answers by now. Also, perhaps check back to my edited answer.

Comment: @Anzurio look at the first comment below the question.

Comment: @Anzurio No problem, Using `System.in.read()` for numbers isn't a good practice. It messes up the other input cycles.

Comment: @UmaKanth The whole code I wrote, IMHO, isn't good practice. I was just trying exemplify. I made my latest update; hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for this possible solution, but since we haven't covered try and catch in class, I'll leave this solution for a later time. :)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to implement a model-view-controller (mvc) pattern to handle this.  Assuming that you are doing a pure Java application and not a web based application look at the [Oracle Java Swing Tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html) to learn how to build your view and controller.

Your model class is very simple.  I would suggest just making a property on your controller that is a Java ArrayList of integers eg at the top of your controller

```
private Array<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Then your controller could have a public method to add a number  and calculate the total

```
public void addInteger(Integer i) {
     numbers.addObject(i);
}
public Integer computeTotal() {
   Integer total = 0;
   for (Integer x : numbers) {
      total += x;
   }
   return total;
}
```

Comment: Why should OP use MVC, if there is no GUI? As OP statet, he/she is a beginner. I think this is overkill.

Comment: Because if you want to begin you might as well begin well with a proper modern framework rather than some command line interface that is totally opposite to the ordinary novice computer user's experience.

Comment: @JohnFontaine: Thank you for your answer, but since we haven't covered arrays in class yet, I'll use this solution for another time. :)